# Position text below image within list item

Tags: html, css, image, listitem

So I have an image rollover effect that requires two images to be within a list item. They are then overlaid each other within the CSS and transition on the hover state.

I have some text that needs to underneath each image, but since one of the image is `position:absolute` it just hangs out behind the image:

[image]

I've tried to wrap the text within a paragraph tag, but for some reason Wordpress is stripping them out within the editor (I'm guessing cause it's within a `li`).
I also tried to implement some `line-height` as well, but that janks it up too.

Here's a sample of the HTML markup:

```
<li>
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-153" alt="lucas2" src="http://localhost:8888/boost/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/lucas2.png" width="117" height="117" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-154 top" alt="lucas1" src="http://localhost:8888/boost/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/lucas1.png" width="117" height="117" />
The Dungeon Master
</li>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.crew ul li {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-bottom: 75px;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-style: italic;
color: #71767d;
font-weight: 300;
position: relative;
width: 117px;
height: 117px;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
.crew ul li img {
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
}
.crew ul li img.top:hover {
opacity: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Overall, I'm trying to keep it a simple as possible so other users can just go into the editor and insert the images and add the text without having to edit any of the HTML within the text editor. Thanks!

Comment: did you test IE10 :-)

Comment: please add the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you don't use a top property to move the image and the text able to be seen?

E.g.

```
.crew ul li img {
   top: 10px;
}
```